# AD7192 send command during continuous read

Tags: adc

I'm using the AD7192 ADC for a measurement unit. On startup I do all the configuration and then set the ADC into continuous read mode by writing `b'01011100` to the command register.
Now I need to set one of the ADC's GPO during operation what doesn't work. It seems to me like already the write operation to the command register fails - I'm sending `b'00101000`. 
According to the datasheet(page 31) I've to send this command while the nRDY/DOUT is low, but what I don't understand is, when the nRDY/DOUT is low and I start to clock, the ADC will send the current conversion so the nRDY/DOUT starts alternating.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the transition cannot be done in one step. One has to explicitely deactivate the continuous read mode first by writing `b01011000` to the command register and then in a second run perform the write operation to the GPO register.

Comment: That sounds annoying to have to do that.

Comment: Think the issue is that if the R/W bit of the first write action to the command register is not '1' (so read) it simply ignores the command.

Comment: I guess so but nice find +1